# Is the use of" Strict Proof" inappropriate in an inquiry / discovery?

Tags: legal-terms

Florida Condominiums Statutes (FS718) require responses to certified email inquiries.

Suppose an inquiry asserts the Association has improperly engaged in X and requests that the association make corrections.  The Association admits to performing X, however, denies that it is improper under pretextual claims of Y, with vague references to the Associations bylaws and Contracts in name only to support Y.

If the goal is to pose a question that **requires** an explanation of what exactly is the passage in the Bylaws / Contracts that forms the basis of the denial.  What exactly is the wording one would use?  Is it "[strict proof"](https://www.floridabar.org/the-florida-bar-journal/books-104/)?

The [cited article](https://www.floridabar.org/the-florida-bar-journal/books-104/) indicates:

> lawyers routinely file a boilerplate reply along the lines of “the
> plaintiff denies all of the defendant’s affirmative defenses and
> demands strict proof thereof.” Spector and Turner explain that such a
> reply is a waste of time, since plaintiffs are deemed to have denied
> the factual allegations in the affirmative defenses. Instead, they
> explain the true purpose of the reply, “to assert defenses to the
> defenses.”

I realize that this phrase is typically used in a defense and not in an inquiry: ideally there would be a requestable "thing" to request a **simplified** IRAC, wherein the response should include the specific language ("chapter and verse") that is applicable to the denial.

If yes, would such a passage be effective:

> Pursuant to clarification of the original inquiry and avoiding
> litigation: The Association has asserted a claim of Y, and alluded
> only to the Bylaws / Contracts in name.  We believe claim Y is
> pretxtual and inquire: Why is a claim Y stated?  Please reply with a
> substantial response to include all *strict proof*:
> quotation of all relevant passages in the bylaws & contracts, any rules (to
> include statute) to support claim Y, any facts and any relevant analysis.

Comment: Why don't you just ask for the specific clause the association is relying on?